# Docker pip3 not installing packages

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have the following Dockerfile and requirements.txt file.  The requirements.txt appears to be processed, but I don't see any output "Installing collected packages" statements like I see when I install the packages on my system without Docker.  In the docker build I end up with an error where the previous package in requirements.txt should have been installed.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.8
ADD . /code
RUN apk add alpine-sdk python3-dev
WORKDIR /code
RUN sudo apk update
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "linqcmd"]
```

requirements.txt

```
boto3
click
python-levenshtein
python-dateutil
cython
# pip3 install git+https://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser
-e git://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser.git#egg=pdfparser
```

docker-compose up --build output

```
...
Step 6/7 : RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 515dd716aa7c
Collecting boto3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/45/810f786ce144bfd19d9f2f700a8cd4358435559a2b88b2c235f7bb3f29df/boto3-1.8.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
Collecting click (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/c1/8806f99713ddb993c5366c362b2f908f18269f8d792aff1abfd700775a77/click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
Collecting python-levenshtein (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/a9/d1785c85ebf9b7dfacd08938dd028209c34a0ea3b1bcdb895208bd40a67d/python-Levenshtein-0.12.0.tar.gz (48kB)
Collecting python-dateutil (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (211kB)
Collecting cython (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/89/ca320e5b45d381ae0df74c4b5694f1471c1b2453c5eb4bac3449f5970481/Cython-0.28.5.tar.gz (1.9MB)
Obtaining pdfparser from git+git://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser.git#egg=pdfparser (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Cloning git://github.com/izderadicka/pdfparser.git to ./src/pdfparser
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    You need to install cython first - sudo pip install cython

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /code/src/pdfparser/
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, pip doesn't install any packages until after it's collected & built wheels for everything it's going to install; this is done to prevent a failure in the middle of installation from causing only some packages to be installed.  Thus, in your case, `cython` won't be installed before a wheel is built for `pdfparser`, which apparently needs `cython` in order to build, and so the installation fails.  You need to install `cython` and `pdfparser` in two separate steps.